# Is there any way to add a conflict to a gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I'm making a gem called something like `ugly_fork_of_foo`.   Can I add something to my gemspec to tell the system that ugly_fork_of_foo conflicts with foo, that both can't be installed simultaneously?

Comment: I suppose I could make a gem called `ugly_monkeypatches_for_foo` instead, but I think that `ugly_fork_of_foo` is more appropriate here.  Both are ugly, though!

Comment: Can you make it a non-ugly feature and submit a pull request?

Comment: No, I've tried, but it's too specific a feature to push upstream.   Luckily I think Rails 4 is going to make it unnecessary so it'll just be a shim for those running Rails 3 in the future.

Comment: Can somebody with enough karma reject the edit?   It introduced a capitalization error, and quoted stuff I deliberately left unquoted because it's unnecessary emphasis.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't define conflicts in gemspec.

Comment: Yep. Might be a nice feature to add, though.